# Drupal services multiple entity reference field

Tags: 7, services, entities

I am building a rest api with services. I have a user that has a entity reference field where they can add multiple nodes at once.

My question is, when returned from the rest api it only provides me the target ids. Is it possible to allow it to return all field values target id, name, date etc.

It would be nice to only have to make 1 call and not a call for each target id. instead of 1 call it could be potentially hundreds.

I was able to do something similar from a node with this code, but need it from the user:

```
function services_erf_services_resources_alter(&$resources) {
  $resources['node']['operations']['retrieve']['callback'] = 'services_erf_node_resource_retrieve';
}

function services_erf_node_resource_retrieve($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node) {
    $uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
    $node->path = url($uri['path'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
    // Unset uri as it has complete entity and this
    // cause never ending recursion in rendering.
    unset($node->uri);
  }

  $node = services_field_permissions_clean('view', 'node', $node);
 if ($node->field_specialty) {
   $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
   $node->specialites = $wrapper->field_specialty->value();
 }

  return $node;
}
```

Comment: This module contains an example that works across all entity types, and will load some basic information about that particular entity (e.g. title, bundle, etc), it would just need to be modified to do a full entity load instead: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupalgap/tree/modules/drupalgap_entityreference/drupalgap_entityreference.module - Be wary of entities with many references, as PHP could easily run out of memory.